# C# best solution for Print invoice

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I would like to design a invoice and print using asp.net C#. I has tried create a aspx page and using window.print to print it through browser. But it was no good results since every computer difference setting/margin/resolution.

I searched the web and tried many way like tbody tbody, css page break, media print, ReportGridView. But still same no good results too.

The template I want to print is consists of a table above every printed page to display information about the invoice. Below consists of a gridview. Since every records got difference length and also difference amount of record inside an invoice.

The invoice should fulfill those condition:

1. print a table a header on every printed page
2. display page numeber like 1/n page in every printed page
3. auto split gridview if exceed page length

Anyone met this issue before can share your tech/coding/skill/comment/experience? Thanks. Some people suggest me save as PDF. What tools would be suitable for this?

Comment: Would you like to use some 3rd party "reports" such as crystal report?

Comment: @User2012384 Crystal report can do this kind of table split? Sorry because I never use it.

Comment: Also please take note that crystal report isn't free [but most company uses this], if you're looking for free reports, you might have to search it on the web

Comment: Ok, thank you for your information. Looking for other free solution.

Comment: If you don't want to go with a reporting solution like Crystal Reports or SSRS, you could use a PDF library to generate PDFs that are then downloadable/printable.

Comment: @João Lourenço What PDF library you recommended to solve this issue according to my requirements? Thanks

Comment: You could look into Jasper Reports as well - I believe it is available as a PDF generation library and as a standalone server to which SOAP requests can be made.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using plain HTML document extensively to display invoice in real world production environment. What you need to do is well-defined the document size. Below is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Invoice
</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .page{
            width: 630px;
            height: 900px;
            margin: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .middleblock{
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .bottomblock{
            height: 100px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Invoice</h2>
        <div class="middleblock">
        </div>

        <div class="bottomblock">
            Issued by,
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this cant control table split very well, friend.

Comment: @120196 total rows and column width need to be calculated in order to perform page break.

Comment: calculation need perform in front end, but every difference computer setting/ resolution/ printer setting will should difference results

Comment: @120196 Even if you use a PDF, it is also has a fix document size. Will this suit different computer's settings + resolution + printer settings? Calculation in front end can be done by javascript. The invoice can be generated either front end or back end. For page break calculation, You upload a zip file somewhere else, which contains your invoice document format and raw data to be printed in the invoice. I can give u an ASP.NET example of how to page break the invoice.

Comment: @120196 and you mentioned about different computer's resolution and printer's settings. Do you mean that you wish your invoice to be generated in different document size to fit the client's pc's printer?

Comment: Hi, actually currently I using js to count the gridview length, then pass to backend and split the table using css page break. But sometime client's computer setting like margin cause some problem like margin cause it exceed 1 page. Not only margin, still having many factor since using web pages to print it

Comment: So I thinking other approach so really solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you did a good job of describing the page. I have faced this issue many times. You have left a lot of freedom as to how to do it, so I will propose a few.

**[Rebuttal to browser attempt]**

I have tried the whole, print in browser thing. It is good for the end user, but not internal docs. I think you were good to stay clear of that. This is a problem I to would like to simplify.

Another person might extract the browser measurements using some javascript. I think the only detractor is possible maintenance there, so it is not bad approach. Not sure the measurements are your only cross-browser concern though. I think the .print function has been limited(unsupported in many browsers, so I had my client use chrome, and it was acceptable).

**[Real Concerns]**

IMO, the hard part is the page breaks. That can be hard to calculate and greatly complicate the issue. So, a good go is to try to use a familiar app like Excel or Open Office. I avoid the interop libraries that can handle Excel files natively. It is very low level. If your going to go that far, maybe use a pdf gen library like PhantomJS below.

**[Bad, but maybe?]**

One solution that has been recently made harder, would be to design your layout as an HTML table, and write it into the response as a .xls file. For a long time, Excel would throw a warning when opening the file, but it worked just fine and could be crudely styled.
However,  recently Excel has a 'feature' where when these (.xls, xlsx)files that come from the web require the user to right-click on them, select properties, and then click the 'UnBlock' button. Not a deal breaker, but a nuisance for sure if the use case is legitimate.

**[Better, but doesn't answer the question]**

In most cases where budget is a concern, we are replacing that system with an even easier solution of just writing a csv file (delimited file). If done properly, we can get the data into a spread sheet. From there, their people are ok with a copy and paste into their actual formatted sheets. CSV cannot provide any formatting.

**[Maybe?]**

Another possible solution might be to use an approach like http://wkhtmltopdf.org/. This has worked in a lot of situations. We have found that it has a hard time rendering style in nested tables though. Frankly, that is easily disputed (could have been my fault at some level) and this is probably worth a look in your case.

**[Possibly?]**

Another possible method would be to send some html to [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). (**See 9/2016 update below for more info**) They have an .exe that will read your JavaScript code file to do some cool stuff, including rendering it and taking a screenshot. I use that to make images from html generated by a text editor. The nice thing there is that it always uses webkit, so the 'output' is the same across browsers. I may not render what the user intended, but I render the final and they work around, for now.
They also offer an API and a cloud service. I get images generated on their server faster than ours. There is a pay 'wall' you can hit though. I get like only 10,000 renders a month for free, or some absurdly favorable thing. (cause I do html text snips, as I said, where they base price on avg page render time of their current users. (process time and output))

**[Our Friends said...]**

If you are .Net savvy and the projects allow, I cannot discount the other poster who referred to the controls that allow for this within the .Net Asp frame work. My boss has a terrible problem with using .Net web controls. However, I have used the very tool you would be in a desktop app. Done simply because it had so many export options. The design process is a lot like Access, if you are familiar. And Crystal Reporting is like Access on steroids, but again, like interop or native pdf gen, requires learning a whole new thing.

**[Done]**
:p

So, that is what I had to say. I hate this issue badly and hope this helped.

Comment: Friend, had you try wkhtmltopdf before?

Comment: In fact, I give a link to it on line line 23, character 60.